# How to get OrgContacts with Addresses with Microsoft Graph Delta endpoint?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to get the Org contacts of my tenant using this Delta endpoint:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/contacts/delta
```

which is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/orgcontact-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Unfortunately, this is not returned the Address of my contacts. In order to retrieve the addresses, I am obliged to call this endpoint instead:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/contacts
```

The issue is that I need to call the Delta endpoint because that returns the DeltaToken that I can use in the future to **only** pull the list of modified/deleted contacts.

Is there any workaround to do this, without having to go through both endpoints, the first one to get the DeltaToken, and the second one to get the addresses of my contacts? (PS: I tried the expand option with no luck).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Currently address of contacts is not returned using this delta endpoint.

Being said that, consider filing [uservoice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) for your specific ask so it could be considered for future implementations.

Thanks.

Comment: Submitted: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/get-orgcontacts-delta-with-their-addresses-and-phones/idi-p/2890048#M413
Thanks!